# LWC tab is not getting refreshed after switching to another tab

Tags: lightning-web-components, tab, refresh

I have LWC component tab "DealSearch" to search the records based on "searchstring".
After getting search result on DealSearch tab, I am switching from the LWC tab to another tab eg:- Account,
then again coming back to DealSearch.
Instead of refreshing the page, I am seeing the old data on my LWC tab.

Comment: Are you using your LWC tab on the record page? can you share some code?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target> lightning__Tab </target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Comment: Only exposed to tab and using it in my custom tab

Comment: directly added my LWC component bundle to Lightning tab and created "DealSearch" custom tab.

Comment: It seems we should not directly create tab with LWC component bundle, otherwise this refresh issue will persist, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Aura Component and put your LWC component inside that aura component.
For custom tab, use the aura component.(code reference)

<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

<c:LwcComponent/>
</aura:component>

Answer (score 0):

after search result you can use this code to refresh.

eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");